# jQuery rowcount change event

Tags: jquery, html-table, onchange

I have a table on my page whose rows are getting increased/decreased using ajax.
I want to have a rowcount change event which gets notified when row count changes. I have tried a couple of things but nothing worked. This is what I tried:

```
$("#myTable tr").length.change(function(){
     alert("row count changed");
 });
```

and also

```
 $("#myTable tbody").change(function(){
        alert("table changed");
    });
```

but these functions are not getting called when rows increase/decrease. Please suggest

Comment: can you execute the function on ajax success

Comment: You're probably better off putting code in the ajax callback. If it's a library with an API, see if there's an exposed `recordAdded` event or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try and check the ajax library i am using. But just in case i want to do it using jquery, Is there a way to capture rowcount change event.

Comment: They mean to do it in the jQuery Ajax success function. So the ARE suggesting doing it with jQuery. ;-) There's no such event as rowcount change, but you know that your Ajax call may or may not create a change in rowcount, so that's the place for it! If you use something like Backbone.js you should be able to tap into the data change automatically, but not being a Backbone.js user, I'm only going by my understanding of it.

Answer (score 2):

Your change events aren't being called because the onChange event, which is the event to which the jQuery `change()` method binds the given callback, is only valid for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements ([reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)).

In particular, your first example is calling `change()` on a number, which should be throwing an error.  Your latter example is calling `change()` on a a `tbody` element, which does not support the `onChange` event.

As far as getting something that actually works you could use `setInterval()` to explicitly check the number of rows every so often:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  if($("#myTable tr").length > 2){
     /* do stuff */ 
   } 
}, 1000);
```

This would check that the number of rows is greater than 2 every second.

If possible, I wouldn't take this approach and would instead try to execute the same actions you would take on a mythical "on row change" event at the point you are actually making the AJAX calls.  If anything, you could create a custom [jQuery event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to be fired on the `<table>` element after each AJAX call (e.g. `$("#myTable tr").trigger('my-custom-event')`,) which you can then listen to: `$("#myTable tr").bind('my-custom-event', function(){ /* do stuff */ })`

On the off chance that you do not have control or access to the JavaScript that is firing the AJAX calls that are updating your rows, another solution could be to look into the jQuery [`ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) event, which is fired whenever an AJAX request is successfully completed on your page. For example:

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(function(){
  if($("#myTable tr").length > 2){
     /* do stuff */ 
   } 
});
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks a lot. You cleared my this doubt and many other as well. Thank you very much. Stackoverflow rocks!!!!!